# dataframe creation in R with iteration choices

Tags: r, dataframe

```
Date    Name    Interval
1.2.2016    ABC Interval1
1.2.2016    ABC Interval2
1.2.2016    ABC Interval3
1.2.2016    ABC Interval4
1.2.2016    ABC Interval5
1.2.2016    ABC Interval6
1.2.2016    ABC Interval7
1.2.2016    ABC Interval8
1.2.2016    ABC Interval9
1.2.2016    ABC Interval10
1.2.2016    ABC Interval11
1.2.2016    ABC Interval12
2.2.2016    ABC Interval1
2.2.2016    ABC Interval2
2.2.2016    ABC Interval3
2.2.2016    ABC Interval4
2.2.2016    ABC Interval5
2.2.2016    ABC Interval6
2.2.2016    ABC Interval7
2.2.2016    ABC Interval8
2.2.2016    ABC Interval9
2.2.2016    ABC Interval10
2.2.2016    ABC Interval11
2.2.2016    ABC Interval12
1.2.2016    DEF Interval1
1.2.2016    DEF Interval2
1.2.2016    DEF Interval3
1.2.2016    DEF Interval4
1.2.2016    DEF Interval5
1.2.2016    DEF Interval6
1.2.2016    DEF Interval7
1.2.2016    DEF Interval8
1.2.2016    DEF Interval9
1.2.2016    DEF Interval10
1.2.2016    DEF Interval11
1.2.2016    DEF Interval12
2.2.2016    DEF Interval1
2.2.2016    DEF Interval2
2.2.2016    DEF Interval3
2.2.2016    DEF Interval4
2.2.2016    DEF Interval5
2.2.2016    DEF Interval6
2.2.2016    DEF Interval7
2.2.2016    DEF Interval8
2.2.2016    DEF Interval9
2.2.2016    DEF Interval10
2.2.2016    DEF Interval11
2.2.2016    DEF Interval12
```

Hi,
I want to create dataframe like above in R. It will be helpful if anyone can suggest minimal way of creating it. Sorry, if this seems very easy; but any help will be highly appreciated.

There are two different names and intervals repeating from 1 to 12 for each date and name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create the data frame column by column while still taking advantage of the automatic cycling feature of R:

```
df <- data.frame(Date = rep(c("1.2.2016", "2.2.2016"), each = 12, len = 48), 
                 Name = rep(c("ABC", "DEF"), each = 24), 
                 Interval = paste("Interval", 1:12, sep = ""))

df
       Date Name   Interval
1  1.2.2016  ABC  Interval1
2  1.2.2016  ABC  Interval2
3  1.2.2016  ABC  Interval3
4  1.2.2016  ABC  Interval4
5  1.2.2016  ABC  Interval5
6  1.2.2016  ABC  Interval6
7  1.2.2016  ABC  Interval7
8  1.2.2016  ABC  Interval8
9  1.2.2016  ABC  Interval9
10 1.2.2016  ABC Interval10
11 1.2.2016  ABC Interval11
12 1.2.2016  ABC Interval12
13 2.2.2016  ABC  Interval1
14 2.2.2016  ABC  Interval2
15 2.2.2016  ABC  Interval3
16 2.2.2016  ABC  Interval4
17 2.2.2016  ABC  Interval5
18 2.2.2016  ABC  Interval6
19 2.2.2016  ABC  Interval7
20 2.2.2016  ABC  Interval8
21 2.2.2016  ABC  Interval9
22 2.2.2016  ABC Interval10
23 2.2.2016  ABC Interval11
24 2.2.2016  ABC Interval12
25 1.2.2016  DEF  Interval1
26 1.2.2016  DEF  Interval2
27 1.2.2016  DEF  Interval3
28 1.2.2016  DEF  Interval4
29 1.2.2016  DEF  Interval5
30 1.2.2016  DEF  Interval6
31 1.2.2016  DEF  Interval7
32 1.2.2016  DEF  Interval8
33 1.2.2016  DEF  Interval9
34 1.2.2016  DEF Interval10
35 1.2.2016  DEF Interval11
36 1.2.2016  DEF Interval12
37 2.2.2016  DEF  Interval1
38 2.2.2016  DEF  Interval2
39 2.2.2016  DEF  Interval3
40 2.2.2016  DEF  Interval4
41 2.2.2016  DEF  Interval5
42 2.2.2016  DEF  Interval6
43 2.2.2016  DEF  Interval7
44 2.2.2016  DEF  Interval8
45 2.2.2016  DEF  Interval9
46 2.2.2016  DEF Interval10
47 2.2.2016  DEF Interval11
48 2.2.2016  DEF Interval12
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. It works. just if the name column has values ABC and DEF and so on, then can I use like 
Name = rep(c("ABC", "DEF"), each = 24)
Please look into updated data in original query.

Comment: Updated the answer. Just play with the `rep` function, it has many features that can help.

Comment: yes; it works; rep is helpful function in this case. thanks for helping in pointing it out.